# why is merged dset not showing as sorted in proc contents?

Tags: sas

if I do:

```
data out.blah ;
  merge
    bling
    zorp
  ;
  by mrn ;
run ;
```

shouldn't out.blah show as being sorted in PROC CONTENTS?  I am finding this not to be the case. Given that bling & zorp have to be sorted by mrn, under what circumstances would the result of merging 2 sorted dsets not also come out in merge-by order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trivial example of why your final dataset doesn't automatically set the `sorted` flag.

```
proc contents data=sashelp.class;
run;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by name;
run;
proc sort data=sashelp.classfit out=classfit;
by name;
run;
data want;
  merge class classfit;
  by name;
  name = reverse(name);
run;
```

Oops, not sorted anymore.

Of course you have two options for helping SAS out here, since *you* know you didn't do anything silly like that - `SORTEDBY` data set option, and `PRESORTED` proc sort.

```
data want(sortedby=name);
  merge class classfit;
  by name;

run;

proc contents data=want;
run;
```

Now that precious SORTED flag is set - but `VALIDATED` is not, of course.

```
proc sort data=want presorted;
by name;
run;
proc contents data=want;
run;
```

There we go - all better, everything's good, and it's only one quick pass through the data, not the full expense of a PROC SORT.

[Don’t Waste Too Many Resources to Get Your Data in a Specific Sequence](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/242-2011.pdf)
, from SGF in 2011, goes over some of this in light detail, including talking about what can set the sorted flag (`PROC SORT` and `ORDER BY`, but not much else).